# Flask-Celery-Redis:Memcached memory release?

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, memcached

I'm running a flask app that is meant to receive sporadic, yet heavy-duty, jobs. I implemented a series of docker containers running the flask app, celery, redis (as the broker) and memcached (as the backend). I use celery to fork processing weight into chunks, then use get() to retrieve all results:

```
# Multithreading
jobs = group(processing_fn.s(c) for c in chunks)
result = jobs.apply_async()

while not result.ready() : 
    time.sleep(30)

resultset = result.get()
```

While this does work fast and fine, I'm having troubles ordering celery to release the RAM used to store task results after I used them. **Eventually, the server runs out of memory and has to be restarted, which is far from optimal.**

I tried using `.forget` over the resultset (and even over each result in the resultset):

```
result = result.get()
result.forget()

...

resultset = result.get() 
for r in result : 
    r.forget()
```

However, none of these released the memory... Any ideas?

Here's how the celery app is instantiated:

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker = "redis://redis:6379/",
        backend = "cache+memcached://memcached:11211"
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

...

celery = make_celery(app)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the point of using Memcached if you already use Redis (as broker)?

Comment: It is my understanding that using Memcached as the backend allows us to actually store the results retrieved by every task (given that we merge all the task results after the forked processing is done), while leaving redis for job handling alone. I can't really say this is the only way to store results, though. Not an expert, certainly.

Comment: Well, use Redis to store the results too. After all, it is made for the same purpose as memcached, and more.

Answer (score 0):

By default celery stores the result of any task for 1 day:

See: 
You can tweak it via:  CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES or
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires